# Components not appearing as intended with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to get `GridBagLayout` to place 4 panels in a frame, one panel in each quadrant of the frame.  I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding something basic with the layout manager but I'm not sure what.  Here's the code that I have for my GUI:

```
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

/**
*  GUI to interact with BookList
*/


public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   //// Main Panel ////
  ////////////////////
  private JPanel mainPanel;


   //// Border ////
  ////////////////
  private Border loweredBorder;


   //// Input Panel ////
  /////////////////////
  private JPanel     inputPanel;

  private JLabel     titleLabel;
  private JTextField titleField;

  private JLabel     authorLabel;
  private JTextField authorField;

  private JLabel     genreLabel;
  private JTextField genreField;

  private JLabel     priceLabel;
  private JTextField priceField;

  private JLabel     reviewLabel;
  private JTextField reviewField;

  private JButton    addBookButton;



   //// Search Panel ////
  //////////////////////
  private JPanel     searchPanel;

  private JLabel     searchLabel;
  private JTextField searchField;

  private JButton    searchButton;



   //// Output Panel ////
  //////////////////////
  private JPanel  outputPanel;

  private JLabel  titleDisplayLabel;
  private JLabel  titleOutputLabel;

  private JLabel  authorDisplayLabel;
  private JLabel  authorOutputLabel;

  private JLabel  genreDisplayLabel;
  private JLabel  genreOutputLabel;

  private JLabel  priceDisplayLabel;
  private JLabel  priceOutputLabel;

  private JLabel  reviewDisplayLabel;
  private JLabel  reviewOutputLabel;

  private JButton editBookButton;
  private JButton deleteBookButton;



   //// Display Panel ////
  //////////////////////////
  private JPanel displayPanel;
  private JScrollPane listPanel;
  private JButton displayButton;


   //// BookList ////
  //////////////////
  private BookList bl;



/**
* Inputs and buttons for interacting with BookList
*/
  public GUI()
  {
    // Instantiate a BookList
    // TODO: Make BookList length a parameter
    bl = new BookList( 5 );

    loweredBorder = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder( BevelBorder.LOWERED );

     //// Instantiate and configure Main Panel ////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GridBagLayout mainPanelLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    this.setLayout( mainPanelLayout );



     //// Instantiate and configure Input Panel ////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    inputPanel = new JPanel(  );
    GridBagLayout inputPanelGridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints inputPanelCons = new GridBagConstraints();

    inputPanelCons.gridx = 0;
    inputPanelCons.gridy = 0;
    inputPanelCons.gridheight = 6;
    inputPanelCons.gridwidth = 2;
    inputPanelCons.weightx = 0.25;
    inputPanelCons.weighty = 0.25;
    inputPanelCons.ipadx = 10;
    inputPanelCons.ipady = 10;
    inputPanelCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    inputPanelCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    inputPanelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);

    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( inputPanel, inputPanelCons );

    inputPanel.setBorder(
      BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( loweredBorder, 
                                        "Add/Edit Book") );

    inputPanel.setLayout( inputPanelGridBag );


    // Title Input Label
    titleLabel = new JLabel( "Title:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints titleLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    titleLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    titleLabelCons.gridy = 0;
    titleLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    titleLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    titleLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( titleLabel, titleLabelCons );

    inputPanel.add( titleLabel );

    // Title Input Field
    titleField = new JTextField( 16 );
    titleLabel.setLabelFor( titleField );

    GridBagConstraints titleFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    titleFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    titleFieldCons.gridy = 0;
    titleFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    titleFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    titleFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( titleField, titleFieldCons );

    inputPanel.add( titleField );


    // Author Input Label
    authorLabel = new JLabel( "Author:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints authorLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    authorLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    authorLabelCons.gridy = 1;
    authorLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    authorLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    authorLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( authorLabel, authorLabelCons );

    inputPanel.add( authorLabel );

    // Author Input Field
    authorField = new JTextField( 16 );

    GridBagConstraints authorFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    authorFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    authorFieldCons.gridy = 1;
    authorFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    authorFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    authorFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( authorField, authorFieldCons );

    authorLabel.setLabelFor( authorField );
    inputPanel.add( authorField );


    // Genre Input Label
    genreLabel = new JLabel( "Genre:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints genreLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    genreLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    genreLabelCons.gridy = 2;
    genreLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    genreLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    genreLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( genreLabel, genreLabelCons );

    inputPanel.add( genreLabel );

    // Genre Input Field
    genreField = new JTextField( 16 );

    GridBagConstraints genreFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    genreFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    genreFieldCons.gridy = 2;
    genreFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    genreFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    genreFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( genreField, genreFieldCons );

    genreLabel.setLabelFor( genreField );
    inputPanel.add( genreField );


    // Price Input Label
    priceLabel = new JLabel( "Price:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints priceLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    priceLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    priceLabelCons.gridy = 3;
    priceLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    priceLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    priceLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( priceLabel, priceLabelCons );

    inputPanel.add( priceLabel );

    // Price Input Field
    priceField = new JTextField( 16 );

    GridBagConstraints priceFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    priceFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    priceFieldCons.gridy = 3;
    priceFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    priceFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    priceFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( priceField, priceFieldCons );

    priceLabel.setLabelFor( priceField );
    inputPanel.add( priceField );


    // Review Input Label
    reviewLabel = new JLabel( "Review:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints reviewLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    reviewLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    reviewLabelCons.gridy = 4;
    reviewLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    reviewLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    reviewLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( reviewLabel, reviewLabelCons );

    inputPanel.add( reviewLabel );

    // Review Input Field
    reviewField = new JTextField( 16 );

    GridBagConstraints reviewFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    reviewFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    reviewFieldCons.gridy = 4;
    reviewFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    reviewFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    reviewFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( reviewField, reviewFieldCons );

    reviewLabel.setLabelFor( reviewField );
    inputPanel.add( reviewField );


    // Add Book Button
    addBookButton = new JButton( "Add" );

    GridBagConstraints addBookButtonCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    addBookButtonCons.gridx = 1;
    addBookButtonCons.gridy = 5;
    addBookButtonCons.ipadx = 10;
    addBookButtonCons.ipady = 10;
    addBookButtonCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    inputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( addBookButton, addBookButtonCons );

    inputPanel.add( addBookButton );

    // Add Book Button Event Listener
    addBookButton.addActionListener( this );

    // Add `inputPanel` to `mainPanel`
    this.add( inputPanel );



     //// List Panel instantiation and configuration ////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    displayPanel = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout displayPanelGridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints displayPanelCons = new GridBagConstraints();

    displayPanelCons.gridx = 0;
    displayPanelCons.gridy = 1;
    displayPanelCons.gridheight = 2;
    displayPanelCons.gridwidth = 1;
    displayPanelCons.weightx = 0.25;
    displayPanelCons.weighty = 0.25;
    displayPanelCons.ipadx = 10;
    displayPanelCons.ipady = 10;
    displayPanelCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    displayPanelCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    displayPanelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );

    displayPanelGridBag.setConstraints( displayPanel, displayPanelCons );

    displayPanel.setBorder(
      BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( loweredBorder, 
                                        "Book List") );

    displayPanel.setLayout( displayPanelGridBag );


    // Separate panel for ScrollPane
    listPanel = new JScrollPane();

    GridBagConstraints listPanelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    listPanelCons.gridx = 0;
    listPanelCons.gridy = 0;
    listPanelCons.ipadx = 10;
    listPanelCons.ipady = 10;
    listPanelCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    listPanelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );

    displayPanelGridBag.setConstraints( listPanel, listPanelCons );


    JTable listTable = new JTable();

    listTable.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

    String[] colHeaders = { "Title", "Author", "Genre", "Price", "Review" };
    listTable.setModel(
      new DefaultTableModel( colHeaders, 0 )
      {
        boolean[] colEditables = { false,
                                   false,
                                   false,
                                   false,
                                   false };

        public boolean isCellEditable( int row, int col )
      {
        return colEditables[ col ];
      }
    });

    listPanel.add( listTable );
    displayPanel.add( listPanel );


    displayButton = new JButton( "Display" );

    GridBagConstraints displayButtonCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    displayButtonCons.gridx = 0;
    displayButtonCons.gridy = 1;
    displayButtonCons.ipadx = 10;
    displayButtonCons.ipady = 10;
    displayButtonCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );

    displayPanelGridBag.setConstraints( displayButton, displayButtonCons );

    displayButton.addActionListener( this );

    displayPanel.add( displayButton );

    this.add( displayPanel );



     //// Search Panel instantiation and configuration ////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    searchPanel = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout searchPanelGridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints searchPanelCons = new GridBagConstraints();

    searchPanelCons.gridheight = 2;
    searchPanelCons.gridwidth = 2;
    searchPanelCons.weightx = 0.25;
    searchPanelCons.weighty = 0.25;
    searchPanelCons.gridx = 1;
    searchPanelCons.gridy = 0;
    searchPanelCons.ipadx = 10;
    searchPanelCons.ipady = 10;
    searchPanelCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    searchPanelCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    searchPanelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);

    searchPanelGridBag.setConstraints( searchPanel, searchPanelCons );
    searchPanel.setBorder(
      BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( loweredBorder, 
                                        "Search for Book" ) );
    searchPanel.setLayout( searchPanelGridBag );


    // Search Input Label
    searchLabel = new JLabel( "Search:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints searchLabelCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    searchLabelCons.gridx = 0;
    searchLabelCons.gridy = 0;
    searchLabelCons.ipadx = 10;
    searchLabelCons.ipady = 10;
    searchLabelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    searchPanelGridBag.setConstraints( searchLabel, searchLabelCons );

    searchPanel.add( searchLabel );


    // Search Input Field
    searchField = new JTextField( 16 );
    searchLabel.setLabelFor( searchField );

    GridBagConstraints searchFieldCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    searchFieldCons.gridx = 1;
    searchFieldCons.gridy = 0;
    searchFieldCons.ipadx = 10;
    searchFieldCons.ipady = 10;
    searchFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5);
    searchPanelGridBag.setConstraints( searchField, searchFieldCons );

    searchPanel.add( searchField );


    // Search Button
    searchButton = new JButton( "Search" );
    searchButton.addActionListener( this );

    GridBagConstraints searchButtonCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    searchButtonCons.gridx = 1;
    searchButtonCons.gridy = 1;
    searchButtonCons.ipadx = 10;
    searchButtonCons.ipady = 10;
    searchFieldCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    searchPanelGridBag.setConstraints( searchButton, searchButtonCons );

    searchPanel.add( searchButton );

    this.add( searchPanel );



     //// Output Panel instantiation and configuration ////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    outputPanel = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout outputPanelGridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints outputPanelCons = new GridBagConstraints();

    outputPanelCons.gridx = 1;
    outputPanelCons.gridy = 1;
    outputPanelCons.gridheight = 6;
    outputPanelCons.gridwidth = 2;
    outputPanelCons.weightx = 0.25;
    outputPanelCons.weighty = 0.25;
    outputPanelCons.ipadx = 10;
    outputPanelCons.ipady = 10;
    outputPanelCons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    outputPanelCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    outputPanelCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( outputPanel, outputPanelCons );

    outputPanel.setBorder(
      BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( loweredBorder,
                                        "Book Information" ) );
    outputPanel.setLayout( outputPanelGridBag );


    // Title Label
    titleDisplayLabel = new JLabel( "Title:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints titleDisplayCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    titleDisplayCons.gridx = 0;
    titleDisplayCons.gridy = 0;
    titleDisplayCons.ipadx = 10;
    titleDisplayCons.ipady = 10;
    titleDisplayCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( titleDisplayLabel, titleDisplayCons );

    outputPanel.add( titleDisplayLabel );


    // Title Output
    titleOutputLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEADING );

    GridBagConstraints titleOutputCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    titleOutputCons.gridx = 1;
    titleOutputCons.gridy = 0;
    titleOutputCons.ipadx = 10;
    titleOutputCons.ipady = 10;
    titleOutputCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( titleOutputLabel, titleOutputCons );

    outputPanel.add( titleOutputLabel );


    // Author Label
    authorDisplayLabel = new JLabel( "Author:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints authorDisplayCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    authorDisplayCons.gridx = 0;
    authorDisplayCons.gridy = 1;
    authorDisplayCons.ipadx = 10;
    authorDisplayCons.ipady = 10;
    authorDisplayCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( authorDisplayLabel, authorDisplayCons );

    outputPanel.add( authorDisplayLabel );


    // Author Output
    authorOutputLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEADING );

    GridBagConstraints authorOutputCons = new GridBagConstraints();

    authorOutputCons.gridx = 1;
    authorOutputCons.gridy = 1;
    authorOutputCons.ipadx = 10;
    authorOutputCons.ipady = 10;
    authorOutputCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( authorOutputLabel, authorOutputCons );

    outputPanel.add( authorOutputLabel );


    // Genre Label
    genreDisplayLabel = new JLabel( "Genre:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints genreDisplayCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    genreDisplayCons.gridx = 0;
    genreDisplayCons.gridy = 2;
    genreDisplayCons.ipadx = 10;
    genreDisplayCons.ipady = 10;
    genreDisplayCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( genreDisplayLabel, genreDisplayCons );

    outputPanel.add( genreDisplayLabel );


    // Genre Output
    genreOutputLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEADING );

    GridBagConstraints genreOutputCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    genreOutputCons.gridx = 1;
    genreOutputCons.gridy = 2;
    genreOutputCons.ipadx = 10;
    genreOutputCons.ipady = 10;
    genreOutputCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( genreOutputLabel, genreOutputCons );

    outputPanel.add( genreOutputLabel );


    // Price Label
    priceDisplayLabel = new JLabel( "Price:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints priceDisplayCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    priceDisplayCons.gridx = 0;
    priceDisplayCons.gridy = 3;
    priceDisplayCons.ipadx = 10;
    priceDisplayCons.ipady = 10;
    priceDisplayCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( priceDisplayLabel, priceDisplayCons );

    outputPanel.add( priceDisplayLabel );


    // Price Output
    priceOutputLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEADING );

    GridBagConstraints priceOutputCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    priceOutputCons.gridx = 1;
    priceOutputCons.gridy = 3;
    priceOutputCons.ipadx = 10;
    priceOutputCons.ipady = 10;
    priceOutputCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( priceOutputLabel, priceOutputCons );

    outputPanel.add( priceOutputLabel );


    // Review Label
    reviewDisplayLabel = new JLabel( "Review:", JLabel.TRAILING );

    GridBagConstraints reviewDisplayCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    reviewDisplayCons.gridx = 0;
    reviewDisplayCons.gridy = 4;
    reviewDisplayCons.ipadx = 10;
    reviewDisplayCons.ipady = 10;
    reviewDisplayCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( reviewDisplayLabel, reviewDisplayCons );

    outputPanel.add( reviewDisplayLabel );


    // Review Output
    reviewOutputLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEADING );

    GridBagConstraints reviewOutputCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    reviewOutputCons.gridx = 1;
    reviewOutputCons.gridy = 4;
    reviewOutputCons.ipadx = 10;
    reviewOutputCons.ipady = 10;
    reviewOutputCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( reviewOutputLabel, reviewOutputCons );

    outputPanel.add( reviewOutputLabel );


    // Edit Button
    editBookButton = new JButton( "Edit" );

    GridBagConstraints editButtonCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    editButtonCons.gridx = 0;
    editButtonCons.gridy = 5;
    editButtonCons.ipadx = 10;
    editButtonCons.ipady = 10;
    editButtonCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( editBookButton, editButtonCons );

    outputPanel.add( editBookButton );

    editBookButton.addActionListener( this );


    // Delete Button
    deleteBookButton = new JButton( "Delete" );

    GridBagConstraints deleteButtonCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    deleteButtonCons.gridx = 1;
    deleteButtonCons.gridy = 5;
    deleteButtonCons.ipadx = 10;
    deleteButtonCons.ipady = 10;
    deleteButtonCons.insets = new Insets( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    outputPanelGridBag.setConstraints( deleteBookButton, deleteButtonCons );

    outputPanel.add( deleteBookButton );

    deleteBookButton.addActionListener( this );

    this.add( outputPanel );

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

  }

}
```

And here's how the window looks when I compile and run the application:

[image: BookManager]

I know that I don't have anything hooked up to display data in the `JTable` in `displayPanel`, but shouldn't the headers be appearing also?

If any clarification is needed let me know, I'll be thinking of what else would be useful and make some updates as needed.

Comment: You serioulsy expect someone to look through that mess? You should factor out the panels into self contained classes - that will reduce the clutter in each panel to whats related to that panel; you can then test each panel layout separately. Its will be obvious where it goes wrong once you have that.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are replacing the ViewportView of the `JScrollPane` with the table.

```
listPanel.add( listTable );
```

Replace with

```
listPanel.setViewportView(listTable);
```

Read: [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).